# Is there any way to password protect against opening any Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection, bloomberg

Recently my department has been charged with enormous amount of money for over-utilizing Bloomberg Excel API. We need to somehow limit the access to Excel application to only a group of people, while access to the Bloomberg Terminal itself should be retained for everyone.

I tried with putting the code below to Personal macros spreadsheet on the PC, so that at every file open in excel calculation mode is switched to manual, all sheets are hidden and password protected, however it is not applied to every open file as intended.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim shWorksheet As Worksheet

    If InputBox("Input protective password: ") <> "TheSecretPassword" Then

        For Each shWorksheet In Worksheets
            With Application
                .Calculation = xlManual
                .CalculateBeforeSave = False
            End With

            With shWorksheet
                .Protect "TheSecretPassword"
                .Visible = xlSheetHidden
            End With
        Next shWorksheet

    End If
End Sub
```

Is there any solution to limit access to whole Excel or to one of Add-ins only to people who know the password?

Comment: Not if you expect it to work 100% of the time.

Comment: Though it's gonna work whenever the First file is opened, Not on the Files that are opened when excel is already open.

Comment: Why not just put a password on the entire Excel file so that they can't open it without a password? When you save the file, go to "general options" in the "save as" dialog box, and create a password to even open the Excel file.